# Logistic Regression to predict match result based on events

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have data on matches played out for the game Dota2. My current goal is to run Logistic Regression to predict the didRadiantWin column. I have kill events that happen for each match so for example:

```
{'attacker': 22,
 'gold': 317,
 'target': 93,
 'time': 2616,
 'xp': 853,
 'matchId': 7046446986, 
 'didRadiantWin': False
}
```

I'm wondering how to properly set up this data for the machine learning model so that I can send in multiple events for one matchID.

Currently I have it set up so event is a list of events. With the label and matchId.

[Current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZx9A.png)

When I try to make the model, I get an error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics

#Start by setting the prediction target
y = killEventsDF['radiantWon']

#Next we set the features we are going to use
data_features = ["event"]
X = pd.DataFrame(killEventsDF[data_features],columns=data_features)

#Here we split the data into training and validation data
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y,random_state = 0,test_size=0.2)

#Make and fit a Random Forest Classifier Model using training data
model = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)
model.fit(train_X, train_y)

#Use the Model to predict the validation data and get a accuracy score based on that
preds = model.predict(val_X)
print("Accuracy of the model is: ", metrics.accuracy_score(val_y, preds))
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OYwf.png)

Comment: Please don't submit pictures of data and error messages. If you instead include them as text it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: Got it, would it be best to add it as a code section then?

Comment: For the error message you could enter it as a code block. For the table [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) for an example to make a table with the SO MD syntax.